# JavaFx Shape Intersect always returns false/true

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, intersection

So, I have created 2 Rectangle Shape and checking if they are intersecting but getting different results each time :

```
    Rectangle a = new Rectangle( 10.00, 10.00 );
    Rectangle b = new Rectangle( 30.00, 20.00 );

    a.setFill(Color.RED);
    _centerPane.getChildren().add(a);
    _centerPane.getChildren().add(b);

    //both at 0.00
    System.out.println( a.intersects( b.getLayoutX(), b.getLayoutY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()) ); //true
    System.out.println( b.intersects( a.getLayoutX(), a.getLayoutY(), a.getWidth(), a.getHeight()) ); //true

    a.setLayoutX( 100.00);
    a.setLayoutY(100.00);

    //only a at different position and not visually intersecting 
    System.out.println( a.intersects( b.getLayoutX(), b.getLayoutY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()) ); //true
    System.out.println( b.intersects( a.getLayoutX(), a.getLayoutY(), a.getWidth(), a.getHeight()) ); //false

    b.setLayoutX( 73.00);
    b.setLayoutY(100.00);

    //Now b is set near a and intersects a visually 
    System.out.println( a.intersects( b.getLayoutX(), b.getLayoutY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()) ); //false
    System.out.println( b.intersects( a.getLayoutX(), a.getLayoutY(), a.getWidth(), a.getHeight()) ); //false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're mixing `layoutX` and `layoutY` with `x` and `y`. If you run the following code (I modified your original code and added some print statements) you'll see that although you're changing `layoutX` and `layoutY` when you call `a.intersects(b.getLayoutX(), ...)` it's testing if `a` which is at (0,0) and has size (10,10) intersects with a rectangle at (100,100) and the answer is, of course, no.

Instead of using `setLayoutX` and `getLayoutX` (or `Y`) just use `setX`/`getX` and `setY`/`getY`.

```
public static void test(Rectangle a, Rectangle b) {
    System.out.println( a.intersects( b.getLayoutX(), b.getLayoutY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()) );
    System.out.println( b.intersects( a.getLayoutX(), a.getLayoutY(), a.getWidth(), a.getHeight()) );
}

public static void print(String name, Rectangle r) {
    System.out.println(name + " : " + r.toString() + " layoutX: " + r.getLayoutX() + " layoutY: " + r.getLayoutY());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle a = new Rectangle( 10.00, 10.00 );
    Rectangle b = new Rectangle( 30.00, 20.00 );

    //both at 0.00
    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    test(a, b); // true, true

    a.setLayoutX(100.00);
    a.setLayoutY(100.00);

    //only a at different position and not visually intersecting 
    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    test(a, b); // true, false

    b.setLayoutX( 73.00);
    b.setLayoutY(100.00);

    //Now b is set near a and intersects a visually 
    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    test(a, b); // false, false
}
```

Comment: using setX() instead of setLayoutX() worked for me, but had to replace them  in all places where I have set position otherwise the intersect was not working. But what are the difference between them they work same. They are quite confusing when it comes to use case.

Thanks :)

Comment: setX() changes the values of the rectangle itself. setLayoutX() is inherited from the `Node` class and is designed for telling an object where it needs to be VISUALLY. A rectangle already knows where it needs to be but other objects might not have an internal X or Y position. Alternately it can be used to override the `Node`'s idea of where it should be placed. Either way, it overrides the default location of the object.